# Typical .gitignore file for Android Studio Project

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I have published my **Android Studio Project** on **github**. 
As Android Studio projects has so many new files like `gradle`, `iml`, `properties`, `md` etc files, I need to know what files should be included in the ignore list.
If any one can share a typical *.gitignore* file for Android Studio will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this be a good starting point?
https://www.gitignore.io/api/android